# Combining indices according to another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two `data.frame`s, and I'd like to use one as reference for combining observations in the other one.

First, I have `data`:

```
> data
Source: local data frame [15 x 7]

           upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units  year     sales
         (dbl)           (int)   (dbl)     (dbl) (int) (dbl)     (dbl)
1   1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235  2008 6073.8563
2   1153801013               1       2  28.61981   108  2009 3090.9396
3   1153801013               2       2  27.99000     7  2009  195.9300
4   1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4  2009  111.9600
5   1153801013               1       3  27.99000     7  2008  195.9300
6  72105922753               1       3  27.10816   163  2008 4418.6306
7  72105922765               2       2  24.79000     3  2010   74.3700
8  72105922765               2       2  25.99000     1  2009   25.9900
9  72105922765               1       2  23.58091    13  2009  306.5518
10  1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1  2009  300.0700
11  1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2  2008  614.1400
12  1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1  2010  269.9900
13  1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8  2008    5.2160
14  1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11  2010  153.8900
15  1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1  2008    0.8700
```

Then, I have `z`, which is the reference:

```
> z
             upc  code
3     1153801013 52161
1932 72105922753 52161
1934 72105922765 52161
2027 81153801013 52161
2033 81153801041 52161
2     1071917100 50174
1256  8723610700 50174
```

I want to combine data points in `data` whose `upc` is the same in `z`.

In the sample I gave to you, there are 5 different `upc`s.

`1071917100` is also in `z`, with the code `50174`. However, the only other `upc` with this code is `8723610700`, which is not in `data`. Therefore, it remains unchanged.

`1461503541` is not in `z` at all, so therefore it also remains unchanged.

`1153801013`, `72105922753`, and `72105922765` all share the same code in `z`, `52161`. Therefore, I want to combine all the observations with these `upc`s.

I want to do this in a really specific way:

1. First, I want to choose the `upc` with the greatest amount of `sales` across the data. `1153801013` has `9668.616` in sales (simply the sum of all `sales` with that `upc`). `72105922753` has `4418.631` in `sales`. `72105922765` has `406.9118` in `sales`. Therefore, I choose `1153801013` as the `upc` for all of them.
2. Now having chosen this `upc`, I want to change `72105922753` and `72105922765` to `1153801013` in data.

Now we have a data set that looks like this:

```
> data1
Source: local data frame [15 x 7]

          upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units  year     sales
        (dbl)           (int)   (dbl)     (dbl) (int) (dbl)     (dbl)
1  1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235  2008 6073.8563
2  1153801013               1       2  28.61981   108  2009 3090.9396
3  1153801013               2       2  27.99000     7  2009  195.9300
4  1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4  2009  111.9600
5  1153801013               1       3  27.99000     7  2008  195.9300
6  1153801013               1       3  27.10816   163  2008 4418.6306
7  1153801013               2       2  24.79000     3  2010   74.3700
8  1153801013               2       2  25.99000     1  2009   25.9900
9  1153801013               1       2  23.58091    13  2009  306.5518
10 1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1  2009  300.0700
11 1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2  2008  614.1400
12 1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1  2010  269.9900
13 1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8  2008    5.2160
14 1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11  2010  153.8900
15 1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1  2008    0.8700
```

3. Finally, I want to combine all the data points with the same `year`, `mymonth`, and `fips_state_code`. The way this will happen is by adding up the `sales` and `units` numbers of data points with the same `upc`, `fips_state_code`, `mymonth`, and `year`, and then recalculating the weighted price. (I.e., `price = total Sales / total Units`.)

And so, the final data set should look like this:

```
> data2
Source: local data frame [12 x 7]

          upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units  year    sales
        (dbl)           (int)   (dbl)     (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)
1  1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235  2008 6073.856
2  1153801013               1       2  28.07844   121  2009 3397.491
3  1153801013               2       2  27.74000     8  2009  221.920
4  1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4  2009  111.960
5  1153801013               1       3  27.14448   170  2008 4614.561
6  1153801013               2       2  24.79000     3  2010   74.370
7  1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1  2009  300.070
8  1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2  2008  614.140
9  1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1  2010  269.990
10 1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8  2008    5.216
11 1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11  2010  153.890
12 1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1  2008    0.870
```

I did try to do this myself, but it took me many lines of code, and I couldn't accomplish the last part successfully. Please let me know if anything is unclear, and thank you very much in advance.

Here is the dput code:

```
    data<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 
1153801013, 72105922753, 72105922765, 72105922765, 72105922765, 
1071917100, 1071917100, 1071917100, 1461503541, 1461503541, 1461503541
), fips_state_code = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), mymonth = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 1), price = c(25.8461971831, 28.6198113208, 27.99, 
27.99, 27.99, 27.1081632653, 24.79, 25.99, 23.5809090909, 300.07, 
307.07, 269.99, 0.652, 13.99, 0.87), units = c(235L, 108L, 7L, 
4L, 7L, 163L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 1L), year = c(2008, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2010, 
2008, 2010, 2008), sales = c(6073.8563380285, 3090.9396226464, 
195.93, 111.96, 195.93, 4418.6306122439, 74.37, 25.99, 306.5518181817, 
300.07, 614.14, 269.99, 5.216, 153.89, 0.87)), .Names = c("upc", 
"fips_state_code", "mymonth", "price", "units", "year", "sales"
), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"))




z<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 72105922753, 72105922765, 
81153801013, 81153801041, 1071917100, 8723610700), code = c(52161L, 
52161L, 52161L, 52161L, 52161L, 50174L, 50174L)), .Names = c("upc", 
"code"), row.names = c(3L, 1932L, 1934L, 2027L, 2033L, 2L, 1256L
), class = "data.frame")





data1<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 
1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1071917100, 
1071917100, 1071917100, 1461503541, 1461503541, 1461503541), 
    fips_state_code = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), mymonth = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), price = c(25.8461971831, 28.6198113208, 
    27.99, 27.99, 27.99, 27.1081632653, 24.79, 25.99, 23.5809090909, 
    300.07, 307.07, 269.99, 0.652, 13.99, 0.87), units = c(235L, 
    108L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 163L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 
    1L), year = c(2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2009, 
    2009, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2008, 2010, 2008), sales = c(6073.8563380285, 
    3090.9396226464, 195.93, 111.96, 195.93, 4418.6306122439, 
    74.37, 25.99, 306.5518181817, 300.07, 614.14, 269.99, 5.216, 
    153.89, 0.87)), .Names = c("upc", "fips_state_code", "mymonth", 
"price", "units", "year", "sales"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"))


data2<-structure(list(upc = c(1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 1153801013, 
1153801013, 1153801013, 1071917100, 1071917100, 1071917100, 1461503541, 
1461503541, 1461503541), fips_state_code = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), mymonth = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), price = c(25.8461971831, 28.07844, 27.74, 
27.99, 27.14448, 24.79, 300.07, 307.07, 269.99, 0.652, 13.99, 
0.87), units = c(235, 121, 8, 4, 170, 3, 1, 2, 1, 8, 11, 1), 
    year = c(2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2008, 
    2010, 2008, 2010, 2008), sales = c(6073.8563380285, 3397.491, 
    221.92, 111.96, 4614.561, 74.37, 300.07, 614.14, 269.99, 
    5.216, 153.89, 0.87)), .Names = c("upc", "fips_state_code", 
"mymonth", "price", "units", "year", "sales"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Hi, I think it maybe clearer if you displayed the tables and to be helpful leave the `dput` starting data at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works. The rows of the final result are in a different order than your `data2`, but at a glance look they look the same.

```
# join data
joined = data %>% left_join(z)

# set aside the rows not in z
not_in_z = filter(joined, is.na(code))

modified = joined %>%
    filter(!is.na(code)) %>%     # for the rows in z
    group_by(code) %>%           # group by code
    arrange(desc(sales)) %>%     # sort by sales (so highest sales is first)
    mutate(upc = first(upc)) %>% # change all UPC codes to the one with
                                 # highest sales (within group)
    bind_rows(not_in_z)          # tack back on the rows that weren't in z
```

The `modified` data should match your `data1` (it has a `code` column too, but you could drop that).

```
final = modified %>%
    ungroup() %>%                # redo the grouping
    group_by(upc, fips_state_code, mymonth, year) %>%
    summarize(                   # add your summary columns
        sales = sum(sales),
        units = sum(units),
        price = sales / units
    ) %>%
    select(    # get columns in the same order as your "data2"
        upc, fips_state_code, mymonth, price, units, year, sales
    )
final
# Source: local data frame [12 x 7]
# Groups: upc, fips_state_code, mymonth [10]
# 
#           upc fips_state_code mymonth     price units  year    sales
#         (dbl)           (int)   (dbl)     (dbl) (int) (dbl)    (dbl)
# 1  1071917100               1       3 307.07000     2  2008  614.140
# 2  1071917100               2       2 300.07000     1  2009  300.070
# 3  1071917100               2       3 269.99000     1  2010  269.990
# 4  1153801013               1       1  27.99000     4  2009  111.960
# 5  1153801013               1       2  28.07844   121  2009 3397.491
# 6  1153801013               1       3  27.14447   170  2008 4614.561
# 7  1153801013               2       2  27.74000     8  2009  221.920
# 8  1153801013               2       2  24.79000     3  2010   74.370
# 9  1153801013               2       3  25.84620   235  2008 6073.856
# 10 1461503541               1       1   0.87000     1  2008    0.870
# 11 1461503541               2       2   0.65200     8  2008    5.216
# 12 1461503541               2       2  13.99000    11  2010  153.890
```

Comment: Not exactly sure how that code works... To be sure, when your code chose 1153801013 over 72105922753 and 72105922765, that was because it had greater total sales between all of its data points, not because it was first in order?

Comment: Actually your post almost works but not quite... If there are more than one data point with the same fips_state_code, mymonth, and year and different upc's that are not in z, your code will combine them.

Comment: I.e., add these two observations to the original dataset and see what happens:
`data[16,] <- c(11111111,1,1,3,2,2008,6)`

`data[17,] <- c(11111112,1,1,6,5,2008,30)`

Comment: The `arrange` sorts by sales (in descending order), so that when it picks the first upc that is the one with the most sales. I'll try your extra data later.

Comment: Thanks. Lookking forward.

Comment: I added a bounty if you would please help me

Comment: @ejn Don't know what you expect with new rows added to `data`, they don't have corresponding entries in `z` so there's nothing to join on and the `code` is `NA` for those entries. (Also applies to the `1461503541` UPC code in your original data.) Maybe you just need to specify what should be done in that case.

Comment: Like I said in my original question, I would like for the entries that are not in `z` to be unchanged. My question would be how to implement that with the function you are using.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to add entries to `z` for the upc's that are not in it already? I.e. make up an arbitrary `code` for each of the upc's that are in `data` but not in `z`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` approach.

First initialize `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data); setDT(z)
```

Re-assign `upc`:

```
#merge to add `code` to `data`
data[z, code := i.code, on = "upc"]

#add a new column with sales by `upc`
data[ , upc_sales := sum(sales), by = upc]

#re-assign
data[ , upc := upc[which.max(upc_sales)], by = code]
```

Aggregate:

```
data2 <- data[ , .(sales = sum(sales), units = sum(units)),
               by = .(upc, fips_state_code, mymonth, year)
               ][ , price := sales / units]
```

There are minor differences vis-a-vis your `data2`, but these are all readily fixed with `setcolorder` and `:= NULL`.

This could also be accomplished in two commands, but it's a tad less legible:

```
data[z, code := i.code, on = "upc"]

data[, upc := 
        upc[which.max(.SD[ , sum(sales), by = upc]$V1)], 
      by = code][ , {sl <- sum(sales); us <- sum(units)
        .(sales = sl, units = us, price = sl/us)},
               by = .(upc, fips_state_code, mymonth, year)]
```